# Filter for filelist box to load only png files

Tags: joomla-3.x, form-fields-types

I am using a field for filelist where I want to bring only png files

```
    <field name="menu_icon"
        type="filelist"
        default=""
        hide_default="true"
        required="true"
        label="JSM_CUSTOM_MENYV_SELECT_ICON"
        description="JSM_CUSTOM_MENYV_SELECT_ICON_DESC"
        directory="media/com_jeemasmsmobile/menuicons"
        filter="*.png" exclude="" stripext="" />
```

What filter should I apply???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `filter="png"` instead of `filter="*.png"` (remove `*.`)